# erro Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, string

Não estou conseguindo salvar o Id do endereço no banco, faço um select do endereço porém não consigo

```
<?php

session_start();


$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$senha = "";
$banco = "cafeteriasp";
$conexao = mysqli_connect ($host, $user, $senha) or die (mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco) or die (mysql_error());

$end = mysqli_query ($conexao, "select ENDID FROM enderecos order by ENDID desc limit 1") or die(mysqli_error());
$id = $_SESSION['id'];


$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$complemento = $_POST['complemento'];



$insert = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO end_usu(END_USU, END_ID, END_NUMERO, END_COMPLEMENTO)
VALUES ('$id', '$end', '$numero', '$complemento')");



mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou processar a consulta e extrair o resultado. Não pode passar um resouce direto dentro uma string precisa extrair o resultado primeiro com a função `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` ela retorna um array associativo que deve ser passado no insert, lembre de indicar a chave que deseja obter o valor, no caso `ENDID`

Mude seu código para:

```
$end = mysqli_query ($conexao, "select ENDID FROM enderecos order by ENDID desc  limit 1")
or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

$endereco = mysqli_fetch_assoc($end);

//código omitido.


$insert = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO end_usu(END_USU, END_ID, END_NUMERO, END_COMPLEMENTO) VALUES ('$id', '{$endereco['ENDID']} ', '$numero', '$complemento')");
```

Comment: Tem algum problema na resposta?